# Convert output to arrays then extract values to loop

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I want that output result to grep second and third column:

```
1       db1    ADM_DAT   300     yes     95.09
2       db2    SYSAUX          400     yes     94.52
```

and convert them like array for example:

```
outputres=("db1    ADM_DAT" "db2    SYSAUX")
```

and after that to be able to read those values in loop for example:

```
for i in "${outputres[@]}"; do read -r a b <<< "$i"; unix_command $(cat file|grep $a|awk '{print $1}') $a $b;done
```

file:

```
10.1.1.1 db1
10.1.1.2 db2
```

Final expectation:

```
unix_command 10.1.1.1 db1 ADM_DAT   
unix_command 10.1.1.2 db2 SYSAUX
```

This is only a theoretical example, I am not sure if it is working.

Comment: try `awk '{print $2,$3}' file`

Comment: @Avinash Raj , good but they will not be in array this is the easiest part to output only the result, my idea is to make them in array not just to show them.

Comment: Then: `mapfile -t outputres < <(awk '{print $2,$3}' file)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a simple bash `while read` and keep adding elements into the array with the `+=` syntax:

```
outputres=()
while read -r _ a b _; do
  outputres+=("$a $b")
done < file
```

Doing so, with your input file, I got:

```
$ echo "${outputres[@]}"     #print all elements
db1 ADM_DAT db2 SYSAUX
$ echo "${outputres[0]}"     #print first one
db1 ADM_DAT
$ echo "${outputres[1]}"     #print second one
db2 SYSAUX
```

---

Since you want to use both values separatedly, it may be better to use an associative array:

```
$ declare -A array=()
$ while read -r _ a b _; do array[$a]=$b; done < file
```

And then you can loop through the values with:

```
$ for key in ${!array[@]}; do     echo "array[$key] = ${array[$key]}"; done
array[db2] = SYSAUX
array[db1] = ADM_DAT
```

See a basic example of utilization of these arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A array=([key1]='value1' [key2]='value2')

for key in ${!array[@]}; do
    echo "array[$key] = ${array[$key]}"
done

echo ${array[key1]}
echo ${array[key2]}
```

---

So maybe this can solve your problem: loop through the file with columns, fetch the 2nd and 3rd and use them twice: firstly the $a to perform a grep in `file` and then as parameters to `cmd_command`:

```
while read -r _ a b _
do
    echo "cmd_command $(awk -v patt="$a" '$0~patt {print $1}' file) $a, $b"
done < columns_file
```

For a sample file `file`:

```
$ cat file
hello this is db1
and this is another db2
```

I got this output (note I am just `echo`ing):

```
$ while read -r _ a b _; do echo "cmd_command $(awk -v patt="$a" '$0~patt {print $1}' file) $a, $b"; done < a
cmd_command hello db1, ADM_DAT
cmd_command and db2, SYSAUX
```

Comment: did the IFS= read the previous output? Because I don't save that to file I want output which I get automaticaly to turn in that array outputres

Comment: then instead of `while read; do ... done < file` just pipe it: `cat file | things | while read ... done`

Comment: I don't get that information from file is just simple print from previous command which give me that output

Comment: @KalinBorisov it is not clear to me what is the problem here. You can either read from a file or pipe from a previous output. Please update your question with more details about what you are doing and what's your ultimate goal

Comment: the idea is to convert those columns to variables and to use them values for further proposes in that case in the loop to use $a=db1 $b=ADM_DAT that will be able to grep additional things with $a variable or $b

Comment: @KalinBorisov so to get a clear picture: you would like to have the values in the array available to loop through them. Currently I am storing them in a way that they appear together, so item 1 is "db1 ADM_DAT", item 2 "db2 SYSAUX". What about creating an key->value array in which one value is the key and the other one the value? With bash 4+ this is done with `declare -A array=([key1]='value1' [key2]='value2')`. Otherwise, you will be "condemned" to use a matrix.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf well I do use `IFS=` because I understood from the OP that he wants each pair of fields to be one value in the array, so that field1 is "db1 ADM_DAT", second one "db2 SYSAUX", etc. But as he is commenting here, it may lead to a different solution. Yours sounds good, let's see if this is the desired one!

Comment: @fedorqui I try your example with file but is not working in my environment when I put the whole output and try while nothing happening, the idea of this array for me is to take those two variables $a and $b because after it I want to use them in loop like `cmd_command $(cat file|grep $a|awk '{print $1}') $a $b` in that case $a variable will grep in file which is ex.: 10.1.1.1 db1 and will take the host and put to the loop

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you are right. I added `IFS=` after checking and I didn't test it. Updated, thanks!

Comment: @KalinBorisov sorry there was an error in my code. Could you try to the updated one, without `IFS`? It should be fine now.

Comment: now your example is working but that doesn't help to make those values work for my loop, could you please look my latest comment

Comment: @KalinBorisov ok. I added another suggested answer with an associative array. Let me know if this helps better.

Comment: I just edit my question hope now is to be more clear

Comment: @KalinBorisov that edit was quite helpful. See my last edit with a full answer. It is at the bottom

Comment: I have issue when have uppercase "awk -v" option do not grep properly. I mean if $a=DB1 is not able to get the result

Comment: @KalinBorisov it is not very clear what you mean, try to give an example. What I would say is that the double quotes in `-v patt="$a"` can screw with the rest of the command, since there are other double quotes around. So if `$a` is just a word, you can drop them and say `-v patt=$a`.

Comment: The idea is when I have `10.1.1.1 DB1` when use awk command is not possible to take the IP address because DB1 is uppercase. Is there possible way to catch all kind lower-upper mixed cases?